# Different missing values as list in different dataframe columns to be replaced with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have got two files.One with the details of my attributes with name detail.csv and the other is the data file which contains the data about these attributes with name data.csv

In the detail.csv file we have two columns "Attribute" which gives the name of the attribute and "Missing value representation" which gives a list of values that are being used as missing values for that attribute.Few of the examples of the same have been given below.

```
Attribute   Missing value representation
Height       [-1,0]
Weight       [X]
Salary       []
Gender       [XX]
```

Now,using this information,I have to replace all the missing values for all the corresponding attributes in my data file "data.csv" with NaN. The data in the data file is represented as:

```
Height   Weight  Salary  Gender
-1       50      20000    F
132      X                XX
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You could look into the `DataFrame.replace` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you read the CSVs and they look like:

```
  Attribute Missing value representation
0    Height                      [-1, 0]
1    Weight                          [X]
2    Salary                           []
3    Gender                         [XX]

   Height Weight Salary Gender
0      -1     50  20000      F
1     132      X            XX
```

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
for key,row in details.iterrows():
    for el in row['Missing value representation']:
        data[row['Attribute']].replace(el,np.NaN,inplace=True)
```

You take all the possible missing value representations for each of the columns, you look through those colums and replace those values for NaNs.